# Upload one video and divide it into different qualities

Tags: php, html, video-player

I want a html5 or any video player to divide the video quality into different qualities / resolutions similar to youtube.

I want to know, is there any way to upload one video quality, for example 1080px,
and have the player show other qualities 360px, 420px and so on.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is commonly referred to as Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP, aka: [MPEG-DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP). Currently only MS [Edge browser](https://caniuse.com/#search=dash) supports MPEG-DASH. However, you can polyfill with [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/)

Using the command line utility [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) follow the [instruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video) given by the Mozilla team on how to encode your video. Basically your will need to produce a audio, video variants and a manifest file.

Upload files to your server and simply insert a video tag in your html like this:

`<video data-dashjs-player autoplay src="://path/manifest.mpd" controls>
</video>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but is not that straightforward. You need to upload the video to a server and then using a server side async job to encode it at different qualities/pixel-sizes. Then you need a video player that allow to switch through different files depending on parameters such as connection speed, device, or UI.

I suggest to check AWS Elastic Transcoder https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/?nc1=h_ls for a high end service (quite expensive) or FFMPEG https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html if you want to do it by yourself.